# Highcharts series click event not firing on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I am working with highcharts where I want to draw a spline graph and I am trying to add series dynamically. I have attached click event to series but I am surprised of that its not firing on first click but on subsequent clicks.

Following is my code.

```
analyticChart.chart.series.splice(dataset.id,0,{
    'data':dataset.data,
    'name':dataset.label,
    'type': 'spline',
    'id':dataset.id+'',
    'yAxis': dataset.id,
    'color': dataset.pointColor,
    'visible':true,
    'marker' : {
        enabled : true,
        radius : 4
    },
    'states': {
        'hover': {
             enabled: false
        }
    },
    'events': {
        click: function (event) {
             console.log("Hello.. mike testing...!!");
             lineChartDatasetClick(datasetList,dataset,index,analyticChart);
        },
        legendItemClick: function (event) {
            try{
                var id = event.target.options.id;
                for(var i=0;i<analyticChart.chart.series.length;i++){ 
                    if(parseInt(id) == parseInt(analyticChart.chart.series[i].id)){
                        if(analyticChart.chart.series[i].visible){
                            analyticChart.chart.series[i].visible = false;
                            analyticChart.chart.options.yAxis[i].labels.enabled = false;
                            analyticChart.chart.options.yAxis[i].lineColor = "transparent";
                        }else{
                             analyticChart.chart.series[i].visible = true;
                             analyticChart.chart.options.yAxis[i].labels.enabled = true;
                             analyticChart.chart.options.yAxis[i].lineColor = analyticChart.chart.series[i].color;
                        }
                        $rootScope.$apply();
                    }
                }
            }catch(e){
                console.log('error in legend ');
            }   
        }
    }
});
```

please help to find out its solution.

Thank you

Comment: Check your console for errors.

Comment: there are no errors in console... only click event not firing.

Comment: set 'hover' : {enabled} to true and see if it changes

Comment: Could you setup jsFiddle with that issue? For me it works fine, please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/kf5nfwLz/1/

Comment: Actually there are number of dependencies in JS files so, will be unable to set it up on the fiddle.

Comment: Hi...@secret_squirrel .. actually that hover option is for only states.. I mean points... but..ok let me try it...

Comment: Hi... sorry @secret_squirrel, but setting hover `enabled : true` option didn't worked for me.....

Comment: Create jsFiddle with only Highcharts code, just like mine. Highcharts doesn't have any dependancies so it is possible and shouldn't be hard. You can also hardcode data.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, any progress?

Comment: That module is no more part of my project. And unfortunately I could not find it's solution.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to this. I have had a similar situation and I found out that we need to set a `kdNow` option to true in plotOptions series.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
   kdNow: true
 }
}
```

This made the first click to work more information for this can be found at 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6817